# Kubernetes how to use round-robin(rr) load balancing strategy among pods

Tags: kubernetes, iptables

I made a deployment and scaled out to 2 replicas. And I made a service to forward it.

I found that kube-proxy uses iptables for forwarding from Service to Pod. But the load balancing strategy of iptables is RANDOM.

How can I force my service to forward requests to 2 pods using round-robin strategy without switching my kube-proxy to `userspace` or `ipvs` mode?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, the strategies are only supported in ipvs mode. The option is even called `--ipvs-scheduler`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like ipvs is the best way to go. That means every node in the k8s cluster needs to install ipvs module, right?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

But if you really don't want to change `--proxy-mode` flag on kube-proxy you can use some third-party proxy/loadbalancer (like HAProxy) and point it to your application. But this is usually not the best option as you need to make sure it's deployed with HA and it will also add complexity to your deployment.

Comment: Thanks. That's something worth me trying